# How to correctly set a UIViewControllers frame when presenting it on top of another view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm presenting a UIViewController on top of another view controller using the following code:

```
let realityKitViewController = RealityKitViewController(localModelPath: modelPath)
realityKitViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
            
// Hide the qr code scanner
GAPP.tabbarCtrl.hideQrCodeScanner(withAnimation: true, completion: {
    topController.present(realityKitViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

In `viewDidLoad()` of the presented view controller I then set the frame:

```
let tabbarHeight = GAPP.tabbarCtrl.getTabbarHeight() - self.view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - tabbarHeight)
```

However, when I look at the view hierarchy I can see that the **UITransitionView** and the **UIView of the presented view controller** both still cover the whole screen instead if having the frame I set in it's `viewDidLoad()`.

[image: view hierarchy]

How can I make the UITransitionView and the presented view controllers UIView the same frame I set in the `viewDidLoad()` of the presented view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the frame in the `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` function instead of `viewDidLoad()`. It seems like your ViewController hasn't all the correct values in the `viewDidLoad()` function yet. Setting the frame in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` will update your frame before every subview layout updates.